# Check if a variable is greater than or equal to a number and less than or equal to a number jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to write code that will take a number from an HTML input field.

- if the number is greater than or equal to 10000 then
  set a new variable to 10000
- if it is less than or equal to set the new variable to the same value as the other variable.

```js
var sc = $('#Single-num1').val(); // Water Amount input
console.log(sc);
```

This is the first variable (sc).

This is what I am trying to get working and the logic makes sense but it won't give me data.

```
if (sc >= 10000) {
  var ssa = 10000;
}
else {
  var ssa = sc;
}
```

```
<div class="singlewateramountdiv">
  <label for="Single-Water-Amount">How Much Water Was Used?</label>
  <input type="text" id="Single-num1" name="Single-num1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: val returns a string, not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a number and do a simple check

```
var sc = Number($('#Single-num1').val());

var ssa = sc;
if (sc > 10000) ssa = 10000;
```

with a ternary

```
var sc = Number($('#Single-num1').val());

var ssa = (sc > 10000) ? 10000 : sc;
```

with Math.min

```
var sc = Number($('#Single-num1').val());
var ssa = Math.min(sc, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!